# Unable to find /usr/bin

Tags: 12.04

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on my machine. Somehow when I tried to boot in next time, it stops me at the terminal window itself. I'm absolutely not able to do anything as it says,
/usr/bin/python : No such file or directory. !
I am surprised as to what made it to delete that directory!
Kindly let me know what I can do.
(Not even sudo or apt-get are possible without python :( )

Comment: i have python in /usr/share. But to copy it, i need to create /usr/bin which requires sudo command. Any way around it to get root permission?

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` is a file (actually a link to some version of python).  Are you saying it won't boot without python, or are you trying to run a python program?

Comment: The whole /usr/bin directory is missing!! Im still unable to figure out how that could've happened.

Comment: Oh, now I see.  Well, without that, missing Python is the least of your problems.  Even if you could create the directory (which you probably could), what about all the programs?

Comment: Yes . So before i reinstall Ubuntu, i just wanted to know if I could do anything. Are the installed programs stored anywhere else? So that i can create back /usr/bin ?

Comment: Well, if you're really determined and know a little about linux, you could maybe recover in various ways. Maybe you could boot from the install CD, mount the hard drive, then copy the files from there to the hard drive. You would be able to create the directory from the live CD, and copy to it.